# Informix: Error -528 Maximum output rowsize (32767) exceeded

Tags: informix, bson

i'm developing  on a Informix database (v. 12FC9DE) and getting the error `-528 (Maximum output rowsize exceeded)` when executing following SELECT:

```
SELECT 
    genbson(row("typ", "name", "sortName", "longName", "shortName", "status", "dates", "comment", "customer"), 1, 1)::JSON
FROM (
        (SELECT
            genbson(row("name", "shortName"), 1, 1) as "typ",
            '{"de":"Max"}'::JSON::BSON              as "name",
            '{"de":"Mustermann Max"}'::JSON::BSON   as "sortName", 
            '{"de":"Max Mustermann"}'::JSON::BSON   as "longName", 
            '{"de":"M. Mustermann"}'::JSON::BSON    as "shortName",
            'A'                                     as "status",
            genbson(row("street", "number", "zipCode", "city"), 1, 1)       as "address",
            genbson(row("phone","fax", "mailaddress", "website"), 1, 1)     as "contact",
            genbson(row("birthDate", "retireDate"), 1, 1)                   as "dates",
            'red'                                   as "comment",
            genbson(row("id"), 1, 1)                as "customer"
        FROM (
            (SELECT             
                '{"de":"Person"}'::JSON::BSON   as "name",
                '{"de":"Person"}'::JSON::BSON   as "shortName",
                'Hauptstraße'                   as "street",
                '1'                             as "number",
                '12345'                         as "zipCode",
                'Musterhausen'                  as "city",
                '012-3456789'                   as "phone",
                '012-34567810'                  as "fax",               
                'info@mustermann.de'            as "mailaddress",
                'www.mustermann.de'             as "website",
                '1980-02-27'::date              as "birthDate",             
                null::date                      as "retireDate",
                'abdgt-756474-eerrr'            as "id"
            FROM  systables where tabid = 1) as a) 
    ) as b);
```

With this statement I try to combine several columns to one JSON/BSON-object. The strings in this example that are converted via ::JSON::BSON are in a stored procedure already combined values.

By changing two of these values to normal strings the error does not show up and the SELECT is successful:

```
SELECT 
    genbson(row("typ", "name", "sortName", "longName", "shortName", "status", "dates", "comment", "customer"), 1, 1)::JSON
FROM (
        (SELECT
            genbson(row("name", "shortName"), 1, 1) as "typ",
            '{"de":"Max"}'::JSON::BSON              as "name",
            '{"de":"Mustermann Max"}'::JSON::BSON   as "sortName", 
            '{"de":"Max Mustermann"}'               as "longName", 
            '{"de":"M. Mustermann"}'                as "shortName",
            'A'                                     as "status",
            genbson(row("street", "number", "zipCode", "city"), 1, 1)       as "address",
            genbson(row("phone","fax", "mailaddress", "website"), 1, 1)     as "contact",
            genbson(row("birthDate", "retireDate"), 1, 1)                   as "dates",
            'red'                                   as "comment",
            genbson(row("id"), 1, 1)                as "customer"
        FROM (
            (SELECT             
                '{"de":"Person"}'::JSON::BSON   as "name",
                '{"de":"Person"}'::JSON::BSON   as "shortName",
                'Hauptstraße'                   as "street",
                '1'                             as "number",
                '12345'                         as "zipCode",
                'Musterhausen'                  as "city",
                '012-3456789'                   as "phone",
                '012-34567810'                  as "fax",               
                'info@mustermann.de'            as "mailaddress",
                'www.mustermann.de'             as "website",
                '1980-02-27'::date              as "birthDate",             
                null::date                      as "retireDate",
                'abdgt-756474-eerrr'            as "id"
            FROM  systables where tabid = 1) as a) 
    ) as b);
```

I use DBeaver or DataStudio to execute the SELECT.
In both the error appears.

My question is: why? ;)

Any suggestions on this?
Is it possibly a known bug or am I doing something wrong?

Best regards
S. Kip

Comment: Seems Informix has a hard limit of 32KiB for row size. JSON and BSON rows are considered to have a length of 4100 Bytes. So with 9 BSON/JSON columns you are at 36 KiB, above the 32 KiB limit (tables can have rows larger than 32 KiB, but they have to use types that are stored "off row", like TEXT, BYTE, BLOB, CBLOB ).

Comment: The first message I got was "-201: syntax error", but that's because I don't normally run with delimited identifiers set.  For anyone trying this at home, please ensure that you have DELIMIDENT=1 set in the environment, or some equivalent mechanism that sets it before running the queries above.

Comment: @LuísMarques: that seems to make sense. ;) The problem is, that I want to use JSON/BSON columns...

Answer (score 0):

To circumvent the 4kB-per-genbson(), which in fact is 4kB-per-BSON, in your query, you can cast each of these genbson(...) calls to an lvarchar(max_expected_length).

```
SELECT
    genbson(row("typ", "name", "sortName", "longName", "shortName", "status", "dates", "comment", "customer"), 1, 1)::JSON::LVARCHAR(400)
FROM (
        (SELECT
            genbson(row("name", "shortName"), 1, 1)::JSON::LVARCHAR(200) as "typ",
            '{"de":"Max"}'                          as "name",
            '{"de":"Mustermann Max"}'               as "sortName",
            '{"de":"Max Mustermann"}'               as "longName",
            '{"de":"M. Mustermann"}'                as "shortName",
            'A'                                     as "status",
            genbson(row("street", "number", "zipCode", "city"), 1, 1)::JSON::LVARCHAR(200) as "address",
            genbson(row("phone","fax", "mailaddress", "website"), 1, 1)::JSON::LVARCHAR(200) as "contact",
            genbson(row("birthDate", "retireDate"), 1, 1)::JSON::LVARCHAR(200) as "dates",
            'red'                                   as "comment",
            genbson(row("id"), 1, 1)::JSON::LVARCHAR(200) as "customer"
        FROM (
            (SELECT
                '{"de":"Person"}'               as "name",
                '{"de":"Person"}'               as "shortName",
                'Hauptstraße'                   as "street",
                '1'                             as "number",
                '12345'                         as "zipCode",
                'Musterhausen'                  as "city",
                '012-3456789'                   as "phone",
                '012-34567810'                  as "fax",
                'info@mustermann.de'            as "mailaddress",
                'www.mustermann.de'             as "website",
                '1980-02-27'::date              as "birthDate",
                null::date                      as "retireDate",
                'abdgt-756474-eerrr'            as "id"
            FROM  systables where tabid = 1) as a)
    ) as b);
```

(I've also removed those ::JSON::BSON casts.)

Comment: Just realizing that the resulting JSON might not be fully valid, containing parts like this:   "longName":"{"de":"Max Mustermann"}"
-> looking to be a different problme -> going to be dealt with in a defect.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post the ::JSON::BSON casts are just simplified for this post. In my StoredProcedure these are variables, which are previously set during execution. And the result is invalid JSON, as you mentioned already. ;)